# Meteor and google cloud storage Cross Origin

Tags: meteor, cors, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

Hello I have been trying for a couple of days to figure out my Cross-origin issue without any success

I am using the latest version of the google cloud storage API and setup my cors via gustils

```
gsutils cors sets cors.json gs://mybucket
```

here is my cors.json

```
[ 
  { 
    "origin": ["*"], 
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS"], 
    "maxAgeSeconds": 1800, 
    "ResponseHeader": ["*"] 
  } 
]
```

But for some reason when i try to upload my file via my webform and I use after that an xhr I am still having an issue

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://storage.googleapis.com//buckettest/Kung-Fu-panda-21.jpg?GoogleAccessId=xxxxxxxxxh@developer.gserviceaccount.com&https://storage.googleapis.com//ilovemeteor/Kung-Fu-panda-21.jpg&Expires=86400&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I am using the signed url method with PUT

Comment: I managed to fixed this, sorry about the fuss was a silly mistake on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed to fix this after go back to the doc, but managed to find the error that was in front of my eyes all this times. I guess I needed a fresh pair of eyes.

when I was creating the URL I put an extra / in my url